# how to know a sqlite database is encrypted or not

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlcipher

As all you know,  we can use sqlcipher to encrypt database and I use it in an android project. For some reason,  I dont want to .use it anymore.

by using sqlcipher_export to convert the database.

So my problems are

1. is there is a good way to let me check is the db encrypted or not and hence decide whether need to have decryption.

2, If there is something unexpected happen (shutdown during migration),  what can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspect the first 16 bytes of the database file directly, if they are equal to the string "SQLite format 3\000" then the file is not encrypted, and is a standard SQLite database.

If something happens and a crash occurs during sqlcipher_export, the original database will be left untouched. Just run the export again on a subsequent launch.

Comment: Thanks. But want to ask more about Q2. But what if something happen when moving exported to replace the original one... I think we can not do much here?

Comment: You should use a file rename to move the file so it is an atomic operation. Either it will succeed, or if an OS crash happens, it will fail. If it fails, the original file will be left untouched and you can re-run the export again. You could also consider something like this: copy file.db file to file.db.bak, rename plain.db to file.db, delete file.db.bak. On resume, if your app sees file.db.bak is present, you can assume the move failed somehow, copy file.db.bak back to file.db and retry the export. Please accept the answer if you consider it correct.

Answer (score 1):

putting @StephenLombardos string "SQLite format 3\000" into a [UTF-8 byte counter](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter) comes back as `19 bytes`

therefore while his answer is correct it needs a little modification.

I would read the first **17 bytes** and check whether they equal **"SQLite format 3\0"**

If the above statement is true then your db file is **Unencrypted**

If the statement is false then your db file is **Encrypted**