# Cleanest way to determine if SqlCipher DB is encrypted

Tags: ios, sqlite, sqlcipher

What would be the cleanest and most efficient way to determine if a (nominally) SqlCipher database is actually encrypted (in iOS).  Note that the technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17348924/581994) does not work with SqlCipher -- the "SQLite format 3" prefix is valid whether encrypted or not.

The obvious way is to open the DB, attempt an operation on it, and see if the return code is SQLITE_NOTADB.  But it's not clear what operation to attempt.

**Added:**  Hmmm...  Apparently SOME versions of SqlCipher don't preserve the file prefix.

Answer (score 0):

SQLCipher stores a unique random salt in the first 16 bytes of the file.  If you are getting `SQLite format 3\000` and the content is still encrypted, it is likely not a SQLCipher encrypted database.

Finally, you could also issue a `hexdump -C YourDatabase.db` and inspect the output, a plain text database will contain a visible schema from the output.