# Is there any way to know what version of SQLCipher was a file encrypted in, programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlcipher

I want to open db files which can be encrypted with SQLCipher3 or SQLCipher4. Since they can be any of the two types, I cannot hardcode the version value in the connection string. Is there any way to know what version it must be opened with programmatically?
Here is what I have so far

```
DbProviderFactory provider = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SQLite");
license = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["license"].ToString();
using (DbConnection conn = provider.CreateConnection())
{
    try
    {
        FileInfo[] Files = sourcePath.GetFiles("*.db");
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            try
            {
                fileCorrupted = false;
                if (Files.Length != 0)
                {
                    string filename = file.FullName;
                    string pwd = "password";
                    ((SQLiteConnection)conn).ParseViaFramework = true;
                    conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=" + filename + "; Version=3;";
                    ((SQLiteConnection)conn).SetPassword(pwd);
                    conn.Open();
                    using (IDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandText = String.Format("PRAGMA cipher_license = '{0}';", license);
                        command.ExecuteScalar();
                    }
                    using (IDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandText = "PRAGMA cipher_version;";
                        Console.WriteLine("Cipher version:{0}", command.ExecuteScalar());
                        command.CommandText = "PRAGMA cipher_fips_status;";
                        Console.WriteLine("FIPS status:{0}", command.ExecuteScalar());
                    }

                    using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) As TableExist FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'TABLENAME' ";
                        var reader = command.ExecuteReader(); //Line giving error
                        long TableCount = 0;
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            TableCount = Convert.ToInt64(reader["TableExist"]);
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

the exception message says
`file is not a database file is not a database`

now i know that this file is a sqlcipher4 db and i can open it with the password
how do i do this programmatically

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18411147/1997232).

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/issues/343) you cannot get the version from the db itself. 

But you can try to open it with the settings for v4. If that fails try with compatibilitysettings for v3. For details see the [docs](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/upgrading-to-sqlcipher-4/3283)