# C# Determine if a SQLite database file is password encrypted

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Yes, I know that it's possible to attempt connecting to a SQLite database, and then using a try-catch if a password is required. This is not clean code. I am looking for a smarter way to determine if a .sqlite file is encrypted before attempting to connect to it. I am using the System.Data.sqlite dll for this project.

Comment: I think that this post could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344345/how-to-know-a-sqlite-database-is-encrypted-or-not

Answer (score 0):

You would have to inspect the SQLite main database file itself.

Excerpt from [The SQLite Database File Format](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html):

> **1.2.4 Reserved bytes per page**
>
> SQLite has the ability to set aside a small number of extra bytes at
> the end of every page for use by extensions. These extra bytes are
> used, for example, by the SQLite Encryption Extension to store a nonce
> and/or cryptographic checksum associated with each page.

Comment: Is there an example you could give?

Comment: I don't have any example, because I don't use SQLite in my day-to-day job especially with encryption.  I just suggested a solution based on the  documentation that I found.

Answer (score 0):

You're only option is try-catch. Since [the entire database file is encrypted](https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki), including metadata, there's no specific bit that you can test on. But I believe that try-catch is appropriate when handling an incorrect or missing password.